# how to end coversation in bot framework using node js

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

i'm using trigger action and end conversation to end my chat..but it closes the current dialog of the chat...
i want end the chat history or data ....

and i'm trying this code..

```
bot.dialog('/end', function (session) {
session.endConversation("End Conversation");
}).triggerAction({ matches: /^(exit)|(quit)/i });
```

Comment: What does _end the chat history or data_ mean exactly?

Comment: If i ask what is your name ..and the answer is xxxx...then the bot says hello xxxx....if i end the chat history ...i want xxxx is not there in bot after i use a end coversation .....

Comment: How about starting a new conversation? That might work, depending on what channels you're using.

Comment: where do you store the `xxxx`? On the `privateConversationData` or the `userData`?

Comment: start with beginDialog @ stuartd....   to store the xxxx in userData @ Pavel Veller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete session.userData;
```

This is worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using

```
session.clearDialogStack()
```

or

```
session.reset();
session.endDialog();
```

Here you will find info about [reset](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#reset) and here about [clearDialogStack](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#cleardialogstack).

Comment: using reset the connection was refused....but the chat history is maintain after in enable the connection

Comment: what do you mean by chat history?

Comment: reset will delete any user data stored.

Comment: i test the localhost.  2nd time i will go to the chatbot.  It was remember my chat history

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple middleware to clear userData/conversationData bags:

```
export interface IResetDataSettings {
    resetCommand: RegExp;
}

export class ResetMiddleware {
    public static data(settings: IResetDataSettings): IMiddlewareMap {
        return {
            botbuilder: (session, next) => {
                if (settings.resetCommand && session.message.text && settings.resetCommand.test(session.message.text)) {
                    session.userData = {};
                    session.conversationData = {};
                    session.privateConversationData = {};
                    session.endConversation("Your conversation state was reset.");
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then setup it like this:

```
this.bot.use(ResetMiddleware.data({ resetCommand: /^reset data$/i }));
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the command “/deleteprofile” to delete the
>   User/PrivateConversation bot data bag state and reset your bot. Note,
>   some channels interpret slash-commands natively, so it may be
>   necessary to send the command with a space in front (“
>   /deleteprofile”)

From here: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq#my-bot-is-stuck--how-can-i-reset-the-conversation